# Converting SQL stored procedure into a Databricks Notebook: How to write IF/ELSE statements & BEGIN/END statements in a Databricks Notebook using SQL

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I'm trying to convert a SQL stored procedure into a Databricks notebook. One stored procedure has multiple IF statements combined with BEGIN/END statements. Based on the Databricks documentation I've read so far it appears that IF/ELSE statements and BEGIN/END statements aren't compatible in Databricks notebooks.

I'd like to know what the closest equivalent to IF & BEGIN/END statements in a Databricks notebook is. Ideally I'd want the solution to be in SQL code since these stored procedures are long (over 2k lines of code) and carry out multiple SQL commands.

Below is a simplified example of a chunk of the SQL stored procedure that I'm trying to convert.

```
IF (@Parameter_A = "value") 
BEGIN 
    SELECT col1..coln 
    FROM table_source 
    WHERE ...
END

IF (@Parameter_A = "a different value")
BEGIN 
    SELECT col1..coln 
    FROM table_source 
    WHERE ...
END
```

Trying to paste this into a Databricks notebook gave me an error.

While the sample above is simplified to a select statement some of the BEGIN/END code blocks tend to have hundreds of code lines and do things like update values in a temp table, delete records, create temp tables to help do different checks etc.

So I'm hoping to hear an alternative that preserves the intent to only run a BEGIN/END code block when a parameter criteria is met and uses SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databricks does not support SQL `IF-ELSE` but you can get around it by using `if/else` in python and then using `spark.sql()` to run your SQL queries inside a python cell.

```
%python

Parameter_A= 1
#using python variable instead of 
#Declare @Parameter_A int  
#Declare @Parameter_A int = 1

if Parameter_A== 1:
    spark.sql(select co1, ... from table where..)

if Parameter_A==5:
    spark.sql(select co2, from diff_table where..)
```

Note: `spark.sql()` returns a dataframe which you can convert to a view using `.createOrReplaceTempView()` or `.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView()` functions or you can directly create a view inside `spark.sql()` like:

```
spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW v1 AS SELECT * FROM Table")
```

Now you can directly access this view in a sql cell with:

```
SELECT * FROM v1
```

Sample example code:
Suppose I have to get `min(col1)` if `Parameter_A= 1` and `max(col1)` if `Parameter_A = 2`

```
%python 
Parameter_A= 1

if Parameter_A == 1:
    display(spark.sql("select min(col1) from table")) #same as "select min(col1) from table" in SQL
if Parameter_A == 2:
    spark.sql("select max(col1) from table").createOrReplaceTempView('v1')
    #creates a temp view v1 with max(col1)
    #or you can use spark.sql("create or replace temp view v1 as select max(col1) from table")
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me get a better sense of how to rework my SQL SPs in Databricks.